# How to convert Eclipse RCP plugin JAR to a plugin directory and vice versa?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

What I have is an RCP application, and a plugin directory in it:

```
my-rcp-app/
  ...
  plugins/
    ...
    com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1/
      com/
      META-INF/
      plugin.xml
```

Then I make a JAR with the same contents as the plugin directory, `com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1.jar`, and put it into `plugins/` instead of a `com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1` folder.

Surprisingly, the app doesn't start. That's from the logs:

```
 !SUBENTRY 2 com.mycompany.root.bundle 2 0 2012-07-05 20:01:17.511
 !MESSAGE Missing required bundle com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1.
```

So, 2 questions here:

1. How to deploy a plugin in a JAR, if I've got a directory with classes, configs etc.
2. Is it enough to unpack a JAR into plugins, for the app to keep working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TobiasWillig already noted, plug-in directories and JARs are indeed fully interchangeable.

But in this specific case I had to edit `configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info` file, replacing

```
com.mycompany.myproduct.ui,1.0.1,plugins/com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1/,4,false
```

with the

```
com.mycompany.myproduct.ui,1.0.1,plugins/com.mycompany.myproduct.ui_1.0.1.jar,4,false
```

I.e., it's required to manually specify a path to the plug-in.

Comment: you should export your plugin properly and use either the p2 director or `Help>install New Software` to install it.  On the next p2 call, it will either overwrite your `bundles.info` or yack completely.

Answer (score 3):

1. From the main page of the Manifest Editor you can open an export wizard. It will create a jar file containing your plug-in. If you want to specify which files should be exported, then go to the build tab in the Manifest Editor.
2. It should not matter if your plug-in is unpacked or in a Jar File. Equinox is able to handle both cases. Note that is recommended to use the dropins folder instead of the plugins folder, if you don't want to manage plug-ins via the Eclipse Update Site mechanism.

Comment: The key is #2 above; you **can not** just drop a plugin into the `plugins` folder in order to deploy it.